# UITableViewCell Data disappears after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, uitableview

I have a tableView in an arc project. When i scroll it even for a sec all data gets hidden or disappears.

I am passing a data from another controller via Strong property.

```
CTableViewController* cTableVc=[[CTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CTableViewController" bundle:nil];
cTableVc.cArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[MyVC pathForAllCardsInDocumentDiretory]];
cTableVc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, cTableVc.view.frame.size.width, cTableVc.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:cTableVc.view];
```

Here is my property

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray* cArray;
```

CTableViewController.m tableView methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [_cardArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{

NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CTableViewCell";
CTableViewCell *cell = (CTableViewCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (CTableViewCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Configure the cell...
NSString* strPath=[cArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.cardImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:strPath];
cell.cardNameLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Card %d", arc4random() % 9];
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your `cellForRowAtIndex:` makes no use of your data in `cArray`. Why not?

Comment: actually it is using i removed that line to create simplicity. Edited to make it clear.

Comment: What is `[self.view cTableVc.view];` in the first segment of code?

Comment: What do you mean by "all data gets hidden or disappears"? Do you mean the cells become completely blank? No image, not label showing "My Card X"?

Comment: Editd its [self.view addSubview:cTableVc.view];

Comment: @maddy. Yea exactly it become completely hidden. It don't even let me scroll to 9 cells.

Comment: Do you keep a reference to the `cTableVc` view controller? You need to keep a strong reference to the view controller as long as you put its view as a subview of the current view controller. Better yet, add the view controller to the current view controller (see the `UIViewController` docs).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is with the code where you created the view controller and add the new view controller's view as a subview. As it stands, you don't keep a reference to the view controller. So the view controller gets deallocated and the table is left with no delegate or data source.

The proper solution is to make use of the `UIViewController` container methods and add the new view controller to the current view controller.

Call:

```
[self addChildViewController:cTableVc];
```

after:

```
self.view addSubview:cTableVc.view];
```

See the docs for `UIViewController` since there is more that needs to be done than just this one line.